# Existe-t-il un manuel pour écrire dans un français très simple et compréhensible de tous ?

Tags: style-de-rédaction

J’avais entendu parler d’un manuel à l’intention de l’administration britannique donnant des conseils de rédaction pour que les documents soient les plus simples possible, sans formules alambiquées, tournures de phrases soutenues ou expressions, certes d’usage, mais obscures. Ce manuel (pour l’anglais, je le rappelle) préconisait d'utiliser un lexique d’origine germanique plutôt que d’origine latine quand c’est possible (*go* plutôt que *continue*) et d’éviter les expressions idiomatiques dont est friande l’administration, comme les équivalents de nos *veuillez agréer l’expression de mes sentiments distingués* et *faire valoir ce que de droit* qui relèvent du grimoire pour le néophyte.

Bref, ce manuel décrivait comment écrire un texte de sorte qu’il soit compréhensible jusque par le dernier abruti de la campagne des Hautes Terres d’Écosse.

Je me suis permis de m’étendre en description pour bien expliquer ce que je cherche, c'est-à-dire un équivalent francophone d’un tel manuel. Un manuel qui expliquerait comment rédiger un texte, de la façon la plus non ambiguë possible, qui soit compris autant par le paysan picard que par le jeune homme qui a quitté l’école en 3<sup>e</sup>, sans chercher à faire dans les envolées lyriques.

Comment: pour le courrier, selon les cas : http://www.apiguide.net/06eco/lettres_importantes/exemples_lettres.htm

Comment: Je ne crois pas que ce soit exactement ce à quoi je m’attends. Les modèles de lettres (particulièrement administratives) utilisent un vocabulaire et des fioritures trop alambiquées *Veuillez agréer, je vous prie, l’expression […]*. Alors que précisèment, je cherches un manuel qui liste toute ces sortes d’attitudes pour les éviter. Ne pas faire de double négation ; Utiliser les mots les plus courants *je suppose* ou mieux *je pense* au lieux de *je suppute*, &cætera.

Comment: en cherchant la,gage châtié, langage usuel, je suis tombé sur http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/langage+usuel.html ; le site donne très souvent les tournures que l'on rencontre dans la presse ou dans les revues de vulgarisation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'[ILSMH Association Européenne](http://www.siwadam.com/hmm/euif.htm) *(ILSMH = International League of Societies for persons with Mental Handicap)*, aujourd'hui appelée [Inclusion Europe](http://inclusion-europe.org), a publié en 1998 un guide d'une vingtaine de pages pour l'écriture à l'intention des handicapés mentaux, disponible en ligne : [***Le Savoir-Simplifier***](http://inclusion-europe.org/images/stories/documents/Project_JRI/FR/100.pdf). Ce document est ainsi sous-titré :

> Directives européennes pour la production d’information en langage clair à l’usage des personnes handicapées mentales, à l’intention des auteurs, éditeurs, spécialistes de la communication, traducteurs et autres personnes intéressées.

Cela peut être une solution à la question. Ce guide a par exemple servi de référence pour [la mise en place d'une version « Accès simple » du site web de la ville de Montréal](http://ville.montreal.qc.ca/pls/portal/url/page/acces_simple_fr/rep_texte_simplifie/rep_fonctionnalites/pourquoi_ce_site). Voici ce qu'ils en disent :

> Les auteurs de ce guide proposent, entre autres, de toujours utiliser un langage simple et sans détour, de présenter une seule idée maîtresse par phrase, de ne pas se servir d'abréviation et d'avoir une structure claire et logique.

Comment: Hmm. La chose est intéressante aussi mais elle ne répond pas au même objectif. Le publique visé par ce que je cherches n’est pas constitué que d’handicapés mentaux mais aussi par des valides sauf que ces derniers ne sont pas toujours des flèches.

Comment: @Fauve je mentionnais ce guide comme possibilité pour un public généraliste : les difficultés des handicapés mentaux pouvant être extrêmement diverses, ce guide vise à simplifier sa formulation pour rendre son discours le plus accessible possible **quelles que soient les déficiences du lecteur** (comme mentionné p. 9 : _« Quiconque éprouve des difficultés de lecture ou d’écriture [...] : handicap mental, autre type de handicap affectant la capacité de lecture ou d’écriture, faible scolarisation, problèmes sociaux, langue maternelle [différente] »_).

Comment: D'ailleurs c'est bien dans cette optique d'accessibilité généraliste que la ville de Montréal s'est appuyé sur ce guide pour la version « accès simple » de leur site web : l'initiative visait à faciliter l'accès _« pour une personne qui a des déficiences ou des limitations, qu'elles soient visuelles, auditives, intellectuelles ou autres »_.

Comment: Dans ce cas, je crois bien que nous avons mis la main sur le manuel recherché. Car en effet, si ce guide vise à aider à la rédaction dans un style accessible par les handicapés mentaux, alors il doit aussi être accessible aux valides quelque peut… mous :)

Answer (score 4):

Sans que j'aie connaissance d'un *manuel* dédié, je pense que la solution se situe autour du « [**français fondamental**](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_fondamental) », pensé pour être le plus accessible possible notamment aux étrangers, et dont voici une description que j'aime bien ([source](http://www.la-bible.net/page.php?ref=pdv2)) :

> C'est un ensemble de 3500 mots environ et de structures grammaticales simples. Ce corpus correspond approximativement à ce qu'un élève de l'école primaire apprend en trois ou quatre ans. Le français fondamental n'est pas une langue à part, mais un niveau de langue appelé à s'enrichir au fur et à mesure que s'exerce le lecteur. Ce niveau de langue bannit les "phrases kilométriques" ou proustiennes, les termes abstraits ou peu connus, il utilise des phrases courtes, calquées sur la respiration et s'apparente ainsi au style oral. Le vocabulaire est courant, si possible sans ambiguïté, concret et correct. Loin d'être un français au rabais, le français fondamental se veut simple, euphonique, imagé et parfois rythmé.

Le document de référence en la matière est visiblement le [*Dictionnaire fondamental de la langue française*](http://www.sudoc.fr/000230049), par [Georges Gougenheim](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georges_Gougenheim) (en tout cas c'est bien le document auquel fait référence cette description).

Comment: En effet nous avons là une très bonne piste. Mais encore, il faudrait voir si un manuel de conseils pour rédiger en Français fondamental fut mis au point.

Answer (score 2):

Ma réponse arrive très tard, mais comme je suis arrivée sur cette page en me posant la même question, voici les éléments que j'ai trouvés qui pourront peut-être être utiles à d'autres:

- le "langage clair", dont la maitrise est un souci constant des Canadiens , notamment dans leur administration; voir p.ex ce site: https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/redac-chap?lang=fra&lettr=chapsect10&info0=10

et puis aussi cet article:

- Roy, S. (2013). Le langage clair en droit : pour une profession plus humaine, efficace, crédible et prospère ! Les Cahiers de droit, 54(4), 975. https://doi.org/10.7202/1020657ar